# org.apache.openjpa.persistence.InvalidStateException: This broker is not configured to use managed transactions

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, apache-camel, openjpa

I am trying to configure camel jpa component and when I run the test case, I am getting this error

"org.apache.openjpa.persistence.InvalidStateException: This broker is not configured to use managed transactions."

But If I am not using any transaction manager , it takes the default one and everything goes good

My Configuration

```
`@JndiBind("jpa")
@Provides*/
@Singleton
public JpaComponent getJpa(JpaVendorAdapter vendorAdapter){
    JpaComponent jpa = new JpaComponent();
    LocalEntityManagerFactoryBean fBean = new LocalEntityManagerFactoryBean();
    fBean.setJpaVendorAdapter(vendorAdapter);
    fBean.setPersistenceUnitName("camel");
    fBean.afterPropertiesSet();
    EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory = fBean.getNativeEntityManagerFactory();
    JpaTransactionManager txMgr = new JpaTransactionManager();
    txMgr.setEntityManagerFactory(entityManagerFactory);

    jpa.setEntityManagerFactory(entityManagerFactory);

    jpa.setTransactionManager(txMgr);

    return jpa;
}`
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with getting the object of EntityManager in your code.

```
    EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory = fBean.getObject();

    JpaTransactionManager txMgr = new JpaTransactionManager();
    txMgr.setEntityManagerFactory(entityManagerFactory);
    txMgr.afterPropertiesSet();

    jpa.setEntityManagerFactory(entityManagerFactory);
    jpa.setTransactionManager(txMgr);
```